# JetBrains plugin for writing (markdown and latex) in a markdown file

Tags: plugins, latex, markdown, jetbrains-ide, katex

Does a JetBrains plugin exist for writing (markdown and latex) in a markdown file?

Of course, the plugin also has to render and show the result.

Answer (score -2):

IntelliJ renders markdown files without any plugin. You just need to create a `.md` file and the IDE will render your code as you go on a side by side window

Comment: At least in DataSpell, LaTeX is not rendered in .md files.